# File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

Tags: python

I want to print the current timestamp in my project, but get error.

My code is here:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from time import time, timezone
from app04 import models

time_now = time()
print(time_now)
```

My traceback is bellow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lice/Desktop/testMulToM/app04/testapp04.py", line 9, in <module>
    from app04 import models
  File "/Users/lice/Desktop/testMulToM/app04/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Test04(models.Model):
  File "/Users/lice/Desktop/testMulToM/app04/models.py", line 9, in Test04
    testTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1185, in __init__
    super(DateField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

You should add the bellow code to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your code(put the code in the front of your python file):

```
import os,django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testMulToM.settings")# project_name 
django.setup()
```